Declaring and accessing the members of a nested structure in NASM x86
How can a nested structure be declared in NASM? And how can its members be accessed?
I've tried using the following code:
struc struct1
    field1: resw 1
    field2: resb 30
endstruc

struc struct2
    field3: resb 1
    field4: resb 1
    _struct1: resb struct1_size
endstruc

But it doesn't seem to be correct

Why doesn’t it seem to be correct? It looks good to me.
